# pyqtgraph changing limits on displayed color scale using pyqtgraph.image()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to change the scale of the data being displayed (not sure if this is what it is called) I want to change the range circled in red to be 3-6 as the default when it launches

[image: look for the red]

Everything I've read suggests it should be as simple as grabbing the ImageView object and calling setLevels() as shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pyqtgraph/farris/pyqtgraph/zwsOOLaK8uw/DSGtUI4RDyUJ). The problem is that I can't find the ImageView object found within an ImageWindow.

Here's my initial code

```
imv = pg.image(amps)
okay = imv.imageItem

imv.view.setAspectLocked(ratio = 4)
print( vars(imv))
imv.setLimits(3,6)

win = QtGui.QMainWindow()

#im.setLookupTable(lut)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):            
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

but it says that ImageWindow has no attribute setLimits.

I tried searching for the ImageView by running

```
print(vars(imv))
```

but the closest thing I could find is the ImageItem but

```
imv.imageItem.setLevels(3,6)
```

raises the error of "levels argument must be 1d or 2d". This makes me think this is not the right path.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I tried

```
imv.imageItem.setLevels((3,6))
```

which produces the following

[image: new picture]

The range is correct on the data, but the legend on the right is not updated correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageWindow` is a subclass of `ImageView`, so all the same methods should apply. Documentation is here: http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/imageview.html#pyqtgraph.ImageView.setImage

These are all different ways of writing approximately the same thing:

```
# 1:
pg.image(data, levels=[3, 6])

# 2:
imv = pg.image(data)
imv.setLevels(3, 6)

# 3:
imv = pg.ImageView()
imv.setImage(data, levels=[3, 6])
```